# Finding the homomorphism between two homomorphic graphs: what is the name of this problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

The "[graph homomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism#Computational_complexity)" can be stated as: given two graphs $G$ and $H$, determine if there exists a homomorphism $f$ such that $f: G \rightarrow H$. This is a famous problem that is well-known to be NP-complete.

Now I'm thinking about a related problem: given two homomorphic graphs $G$ and $H$, find $f: G \rightarrow H$. Does this problem have a name? Is its complexity class known?

Comment: Your problem is not a decision problem. In particular, it cannot be NP-complete or NP-hard.

Comment: Good point. Fixed my question

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of cases that we can dispose of straight away.

A *self-edge* on some vertex $v$ is an edge $v \rightarrow v$. If $H$ has even one vertex with a self-edge, then it's trivial to construct a homomorphism which maps all vertices to that vertex and all edges to that edge.

Similarly, if $H$ doesn't have a single vertex with a self-edge but $G$ has, no homomorphism exists.

Finally, we can deal with the case where $G$ has no self-edges. Then $G$ must be a *chromatic* graph: for some $k$, the vertices of $G$ can be assigned $k$ colours such that the start and end of each edge do not share the same colour.

Denote the complete graph with $k$ vertices by $K_k$.

Exercise: Show that a homomorphism $f : G \rightarrow K_k$ describes a $k$-colouring of $G$. Conversely, show that every $k$-colouring of $G$ can be represented as a homomorphism $f : G \rightarrow K_k$.

So any solution to your problem is also a solution to the $k$-colouring problem.

The decision problem of testing a mapping to see if it is a graph homomorphism is trivially in P. It follows that your problem is FNP-complete.